# Kendo grid - summary fields in a single row

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, row, aggregation, summary

is it possible to sum fields in a row of kendo grid? I'm able to summary columns in table but not a single rows. I've set aggregation for each field but it works only for "footerTemplate". I hope my question is clear... Thanks for any help!

Example:

User      | Jan   | Feb   | Mar  | Sum

John      | 1000  | 2000  | 3000 | ???

Peter     | 1500  | 2500  | 3500 | ???

*footerTemplate SUM*       | **2500**  | **4500**  | **6500** | ???

In DataSource I define aggregation and group:

```
aggregate: [ 
  { field: "Jan", aggregate: "sum" },
  { field: "Feb", aggregate: "sum" }, ...
],
...
group: {field: "???",  aggregates: [ { field: "Jan", aggregate: "sum" }, { field: "Feb", aggregate: "sum" } ]}
...
columns: [
  ...,
  { "field": "???", "title": "Summary", "format": "{0:n0}", "footerTemplate": "#= kendo.toString(sum, \"C\")#", "groupFooterTemplate": "#= kendo.toString(sum, \"C\")#" },
]
```

Thanks very much for any answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way of getting it is defining an extra column (lets call it `Sum`) in the `Grid` that computes the value for you. This extra column uses a template for compute the value and this computation can be either invoking a function in your model (the cleanest) or directly hard code it.

Example:

```
// DataSource Definition
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { Id:1, User: "John", Jan : 1000, Feb: 2000, Mar: 3000 },
        { Id:2, User: "Peter", Jan : 1500, Feb: 2500, Mar: 3500 }
    ],
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: 'number' },
                User: { type: 'string' },
                Jan: { type: 'number' },
                Feb: { type: 'number' },
                Mar: { type: 'number' }
            },
            Sum: function() {
                return this.Jan + this.Feb + this.Mar;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Where I've defined a `Sum` function that computes the total for the fields `Jan` through `Mar`.

Then the Grid definition would be:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "User" },
        { field: "Jan" },
        { field: "Feb" },
        { field: "Mar" },
        { title: "Sum", template: "#= Sum() #" }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

**NOTE:** I'm not including the aggregates since you do not have problems with this.

As you can see the `Sum` column computes the sum when invoked from the template. See it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Bz3Y5/

The second approach would be not having `Sum` function but computing the value in the template.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "User" },
        { field: "Jan" },
        { field: "Feb" },
        { field: "Mar" },
        { title: "Sum", template: "#= data.Jan + data.Feb + data.Mar #" }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

See it implemented here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Bz3Y5/2/

The disadvantage with this two approaches is that you have to compute the total each time the template is invoked so if you paginate you might have some extra processing. If you want to avoid this, then you can use `parse` function in the `DataSource`:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { Id:1, User: "John", Jan : 1000, Feb: 2000, Mar: 3000 },
        { Id:2, User: "Peter", Jan : 1500, Feb: 2500, Mar: 3500 }
    ],
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: 'number' },
                User: { type: 'string' },
                Jan: { type: 'number' },
                Feb: { type: 'number' },
                Mar: { type: 'number' }
            }
        },
        parse: function (d) {
            $.each(d, function (idx, elem) {
                elem.Sum = elem.Jan + elem.Feb + elem.Mar;
            });
            return d;
        }
    }
});
```

This `parse` function receives the original data and transforms it in whatever you want, adding, removing, transforming any field in the original data and before sending it to the Grid.

You can see this last approach here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Bz3Y5/3/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I found solution finally too, very similar to yours second approach but your solution with parse function is the best and exactly the one I was looking for. Many thanks